# TA12L-100 current sensor max current

Tags: current, sensing

I want to buy this current sensor from eBay. I couldn't find how it works, but I presume it works like the other ones through induction. On many sites it says it has a maximum current of 5 amps, but I'm wondering what would happen if a higher current would be used? Specifically I'd like to sense something up top 15 amps.

Comment: If you only want to know if the appliance is on or not, why not make your own sensor. It should be easy to get a few mV of AC, either from a simple transformer made from a metal ring, or a Rogowski coil wound from thin wire. I've even had some luck just placing a 100 turn coil adjacent to one of the conductors.

Comment: I tried to make one, but it didn't work. I used some piano wire (the only thing ferrous that I had at hand) and some thin multifilar wire. It was also pretty big. I want to buy one ready made to eliminate my possible (probable :)) construction faults (and also to make it fit better in a junction box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core will tend to saturate so you'll lose accuracy. How much is anyone's guess, but if it really works down to 20Hz/5A it might not be too bad at 60Hz/15A. I have doubts- would not be gobsmacked if it reads 30 or 40% low at 15A. Otherwise they put 2x ~ 3x as much core in there as they needed.

Comment: So if I don't need the accuracy I could use it? I just need to know if an appliance is on, not to calculate the current. I was worried that I might cause overheating or something :-)

Comment: It should work well for that purpose. It won't overheat so long as you put a wire capable of 15A through the hole.

Comment: I'm thinking of a 14 AWG wire from an extension cord that will be connected to an outlet.

Comment: Should be okay if the cord is rated for that current.